# Play two videos with MPMoviePlayerView Controller

Tags: iphone, video, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an application for IPAD and I need to play two videos one after another but can not find how. I'm using MPMoviePlayerViewController to do it and do not know how to launch a share after the first video to be played and start the second. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

what about using MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification from [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3) ?

In that method:

> [..] you can also change the currently playing movie by changing the value in the contentURL  property. [..]

(still from documentation)

hope it helps